# Spectrum of the modular automorphism

Tags: operator-algebras, von-neumann-algebras

[image]

The Theorem is from Takesaki's book. I was confused by the result which is marked green.

How to derive $sp(\sigma^{\varphi})\subset (2\pi/T)\Bbb Z$.

I tried to search the Propositions and Theorems in the previous Chapter and I cannot find the similar conclusion and I even did not find the precise definition of the $sp(\sigma^{\varphi})$.

Answer (score 1):

As indicated in the book's index, $\operatorname{Sp}(\alpha)$ is the *Arveson spectrum* of the dynamical system $\{M,G,\alpha\}$, defined on page 313.

The assumption in the second part of the proof is that $M$ is of type III$_\lambda$. By definition (III.1.5), this means that the flow of weights has period $T$ and $T=-\log\lambda$. The explanation for $\log\lambda=\frac{2\pi}T$ seems to stem from the previous section on actions,  but I'm not expert.

Comment: How to use the definition of Arveson spectrum to verify that $sp(\sigma^{\varphi})\subset (2\pi/T)\Bbb Z$. It seems complicated.

Comment: I haven't read enough to understand how it's done in the book. But there seems to be a long explanation on the action and its period.